# User changing background image

Tags: swift3, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller, wallpaper

I will do my very best to explain my issue.

I have 30 images in a gallery giving the user the choice to select an image and change the main view controller background image, much like the Apple wallpapers in the settings menu.

My problem is, I don't know how to implement this.

I though image picker was a solution but as the images are stored inside the app, is this the best?

I have a collection view controller displaying 30 images in cells. Click on the cell and it takes you to selected image in a new vc. How do I have a "Select" button from that image (or the other 29 images) vc to the main vc? Each image vc has a storyboard ID.

I haven't attached code because I haven't written any worth sharing.  I'm stuck.

Please be kind to me, I'm just learning in this male dominated world.

Merci beaucoup